React native app crash on launch on Android after Target SDK version upgrade to 34
Facing issue with running app on Android after upgrading Target SDK Version from 33 to 34
Upgraded gradle from 6.9 to 7.5 and Gradle Plugin from 4.0.1 to 7.4.0
React Native: 0.66.5
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bigiron.auctionapp, PID: 12850
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.appName.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created

Try updating the RN version

this will help: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.66.5&to=0.73.8

I also face a crash on app launch when I upgrade my build.gradle to target SDK version to 34:
`buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
 compileSdkVersion = 34
 targetSdkVersion = 34`

which was due to a BroadcastReceiver Crash below article helps me with this
https://medium.com/@siddhantshelake/fixing-broadcastreceiver-crashes-and-metro-server-issues-in-android-14-3b7d05939a43

This resolves the app crash but now after app launch getting error "One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts"

Please ensure that the imports are added in MainApplication.java.

I reviewed all imports nothing is missing. Still the same error

I resolved error "One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts" by fixing react-native-orientation
